# Limitar o resultado de um valor (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

No meu SQL tenho a seguinte condição:

```
CASE 
    WHEN MF.Tipo_veiculo = 'M' THEN ((PBI.Peso_bruto - PBF.Peso_bruto) / 9540) * 100
END AS TAXA
```

Porém, o resultado dessa conta as vezes passa de 100 e eu gostaria de travar em 100 caso ultrapasse, isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema, é utilizando a função [least](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest), segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN MF.Tipo_veiculo = 'M' THEN LEAST(((PBI.Peso_bruto - PBF.Peso_bruto) / 9540) * 100, 100)
END AS TAXA
```

Repare que ao utilizar a função `LEAST`, estou passando explicitamente o valor 100, para que no caso de haver valores maiores que 100, então o valor 100 será exibido como um valor padrão.

Comment: Obrigado por responder! Me deparei com esse erro: 'LEAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: eu escrevi a query específica para sql-server. que é a tag que está presente na sua pergunta.  @MatheusPrado, junto com a resposta em coloquei um link para a documentação do comando do próprio manual do sgbd.